# how to iterate with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a function minmax, that basically iterates over a dataframe of transactions. I want to calculate a set of calculations including the id, so accountstart,accountend are the two fields calculated. The intention is to make this calculations my month and account.

So when I do:

```
 df1 = df.loc[df['accountNo']==10]
 minmax(df1) it works.
```

What I can't do is:

```
 df.groupby('accountNo').apply(minmax)
```

When I do:

```
 grouped = df.groupby('accountNo')
 for i,j in grouped:
    print(minmax(j))
```

It does the computation, print the result, but without print it complains about KeyError: -1 that is itertools. So akward.

How to tackle that in Pandas?

```
def minmax(x):
  dfminmax = {}

  accno = set(x['accountNo'])
  accno = repr(accno)
  kgroup = x.groupby('monthStart')['cumsum'].sum()
  maxt = x['startbalance'].max()
  kgroup = pd.DataFrame(kgroup)
  kgroup['startbalance'] = 0
  kgroup['startbalance'][0] = maxt
  kgroup['endbalance'] = 0
  kgroup['accountNo'] = accno
  kgroup['accountNo'] = kgroup['accountNo'].str.strip('{}.0')
  kgroup.reset_index(inplace=True)
  for idx, row in kgroup.iterrows():
        if kgroup.loc[idx,'startbalance']==0:
                kgroup.loc[idx,'startbalance']=kgroup.loc[idx-1,'endbalance'], 
        if kgroup.loc[idx,'endbalance']==0:
                kgroup.loc[idx,'endbalance'] = 
  kgroup.loc[idx,'cumsum']+kgroup.loc[idx,'startbalance']

  dfminmax['monthStart'].append(kgroup['monthStart'])
  dfminmax['startbalance'].append(kgroup['startbalance'])
  dfminmax['endbalance'].append(kgroup['endbalance'])
  dfminmax['accountNo'].append(kgroup['accountNo'])

return dfminmax
```

Answer (score 1):

`.apply()` takes `pandas` `Series` as inputs, not `DataFrames`. Using `.agg`, as in `df.groupby('accountNo').agg(yourfunction)` should yield better results. Be sure to check out the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) for details on implementation.